# If f(x)dx is a rectangle with height f(x) and width dx, what is f(z)dz in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition

I am trying to intuitively understand the multiplication $f(z)dz$ in complex analysis. For instance, $f(x)dx$, we are all aware, is a rectangle with height $f(x)$ and width $dx$ so its multiplication is an area of this rectangle. Is there a similar way to visualize $f(z)dz$ also?

Comment: Argh. I'm sorry, $f(x)dx$ does not represent the area of a rectangle. $dx$ is not a number, it's a differential form. (I couldn't let it go.)

Comment: I had area under the curve using integrals in my mind while assuming $f(x)dx$ as area of each rectangle under the curve. Would it be wrong to assume dx as the width of rectangle even in that context?

Comment: Certainly you can think of it in some sense as the limit of areas of rectangles of width $\delta x$ as that width tends to zero, but whether there's an equivalent limit for $f(z) dz$ I'll leave to others.

Answer (score 2):

You can interpret the function $f$ as a "complex force field" defined in the region $\Omega$; the function value $f(z)$ is then the force vector attached to the point $z$. On the other hand $dz$ represents an infinitesimal movement from $z$ to $z+dz$. The product $f(z)\>dz$ is then the "complex work" done when a mass point moves under the influence of $f$ from $z$ to $z+dz$.

Note that the notion of line integral picks up this intuition:
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\>dz=\lim_\ldots \sum_{k=1}^N f(z_k)(z_k-z_{k-1})\ ,$$
where
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto z(t)\qquad(a\leq t\leq b)$$
is a curve in $\Omega$, and $z_k=z(t_k)$ for a partition $a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_N=b$.

Answer (score 1):

When you are taking an integral with respect to $z$ you are integrating along curves in the complex plane. Let us assume there is just one continuous curve, without loss of generality. Then the curve can be parameterized in terms of a single real variable, say $t$, so there are real valued functions $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ such that $z=p(t)+iq(t)$. We may assume that the parametrization has domain $[0,1]$. The integral becomes

$$\int f(p(t)+iq(t))d(p(t)+iq(t)) =\int_0^1 f(p(t)+iq(t))(p'(t)+iq'(t))dt$$

This allows you to interpret dt analogously to the width of a rectangle, but the base of the rectangle is twisted along the curve of integration. The integrand may be interpreted as the height of the rectangle, even though it is complex: it splits up into a "real height" and an "imaginary height".